# How to add image in R markdown on Mac. I used this but did not work ![This ](c:/Macintosh HD/Users/josephjaiyeola/Desktop/Rversion.png)

Tags: r

How to add image in R markdown on Mac. I used this but did not work:

```
![This ](c:/Macintosh HD/Users/josephjaiyeola/Desktop/Rversion.png)
```

I got this error :

> Error: unexpected '[' in "! ["

Comment: Check if there's no extra space as the error message seems to show : `![` and not `! [`

Comment: you can also use `knitr::include_graphics()` inside an R chunk.

Comment: If you're on a mac, why are you using `c:/`? I thought the drive-letter thing was only applicable to windows.

Comment: That error occurs when the *R interpreter* is given that text. Namely, `! [1]` gives that error. That suggests that you are putting that *rmarkdown text* (which is not R) into an R code block. If this isn't clear, then it would really help to see more of the document to be able to reproduce it (as otherwise I think it'll be closed as unreproducible or a typo).